# Can I ask This in the main forum? Why do similar letters in En and Ru have different pronunciations?

Tags: discussion

I don't know whether my question is appropriate for the forum or not. I'll appreciate if you show me  the right way.

Why do similar English and Russian letters have different pronunciations?

for example "B" in Russian is not same "B" in English. same for "P" which is "R" etc. I am interested in historical reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this question is on topic for the site, and, in fact, it has been [asked](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8937/why-are-there-letters-which-look-similar-but-are-pronounced-differently-between) before.